# What are the necessary/sufficient conditions for a Fourier transform to have at least $k$ roots?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

Let $f(x)$ be a symmetric function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and $\hat f(k)$ be it's Fourier transform.

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $\hat f(k)$ to have at least $n$ roots?
I have had a look at some literature on conditions for $\hat f(k)$ to have zero roots (such as [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-positivity-of-fourier-transforms/D232B9DEB4819E4D2FF17E8162B8B066)).
Can someone point to towards helpful literature or results on the existence of at least $n$ roots?

Also, are there any related results for Hankel transforms (for a related 2D problem)?